# svn checkout on windows server

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I am using VisualSVN Server. I have 2 repositories on my Windows Server computer. I have a post commit hook on one that copies all the content of the repository 1 to folder c:\my\path\to\foler\one

I want to create a second hook that copies all the content from repository 2 to c:\my\path\to\foler\Two

After copying everything and correcting paths I am getting an error that c:\my\path\to\foler\two "is not a working copy"

How do I do a `svn checkout` to c:\my\path\to\foler\two from repository 2 ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess, you try running `svn update` against `c:\my\path\to\foler\two` in your hook script. But you have to `svn checkout` the working copy to `c:\my\path\to\foler\two` first of all.

You are getting "is not a working copy" error just because you run `svn update` against a directory which is not a working copy. You have to checkout the working copy to this directory.

Comment: @Yebach http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.initial.html use `file:///C:\PathToRepository` URL in the hook script to access the repo directly on disk.